# Accept or decline access email sent even though I already have permission to access the site

Tags: permissions, share

Why do users have to ask permission to access a site when they already have access rights in that site?
This is happening when someone is using the Share feature

Comment: "This is happening when someone is using the Share feature" ... can you explain more in details. Steps or screenshots would be helpful.